# ant stop build if there are errors

Tags: java, android, ant, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have ant building android projects from the command line. It won't stop for android specific errors, or maybe java errors too. But this can cause some pretty spectacular crashes that I won't normally see from the IDE

how can I make ant stop for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ant` fails only case of compile time errors. `ant` script invokes `javac` to compile your source files. If there are any compile time errors, it fails. `ant/javac` can't really predict runtime errors.